# How to call this defined function into mysql query so that i can > into importdate

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x

#How to can i call this lastSuccessfulRun function and will compare to table of my query

```
lastSuccessfulRun = get_lastrun(appointmentType)

query =f"""
DECLARE @MyDateTime datetime = GETDATE();
    SELECT 
          'SMS','Active','2021-02-01T00:01:00.001Z','America/Denver','NONE',
        A.CaseNumber,A.AppointmentDateTime,A.AppointmentType,A.AppointmentInterviewType,CONCAT ('+1',B.ClientInfoData),
          CASE WHEN A.AppointmentDateTime > @MyDateTime THEN 'CONFIRMATION' END AS Type
        FROM ASPEN.tbl_Appointment A LEFT JOIN ASPEN.tbl_ClientInfo B ON A.CaseNumber = B.CaseNumber 
        WHERE A.AppointmentType = '{appointmentType}' AND B.ClientInfoData is not null
"""

cursor.execute(query)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
print (rows)
```

Comment: Your title says "MySQL" but your tags say "SQL Server", what RDBMS are you *really* using? The syntax looks like T-SQL with the usage of `GETDATE()`. The above also looks like it's open to injection with the clause `A.AppointmentType = '{appointmentType}'`. Finally, Why alias `tbl_ClientInfo ` with `B`? There's no character "b" in `tbl_ClientInfo `.

Comment: how can i get the lastSuccessfulRun in my query so that i can compare it with the appointment date